# WooCommerce - Renaming bulk actions complete status in admin order list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

I've already renamed my order status 'completed' to 'paid' using this code

```
function wc_renaming_order_status( $order_statuses ) {
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
        if ( 'wc-completed' === $key ) {
            $order_statuses['wc-completed'] = _x( 'Paid', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wc_renaming_order_status' );
```

And now I need to rename bulk options in my order list admin.
I've used this code:

```
add_action('admin_footer-edit.php', 'custom_bulk_admin_footer');
function custom_bulk_admin_footer() {

    global $post_type;

     if($post_type == 'shop_order') {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('<option>').val('shipped').text('<?php _e('Mark as shipped')?>').appendTo("select[name='action']");
    jQuery('<option>').val('shipped').text('<?php _e('Mark as shipped')?>').appendTo("select[name='action2']");
  });
</script>
<?php
 }
}
```

But only worked for add a new option, what I really need is to rename bulk option 'Mark as completed' to 'Mark as paid'

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible using wordpress [**`gettex()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext) native function. You will get this:

[image]

This is the code:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'wc_renaming_bulk_status', 20, 3);
function wc_renaming_bulk_status( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {

    if( is_admin()) {
        if( $untranslated_text == 'Mark complete' )
            $translated_text = __( 'Mark paid','theme_text_domain' );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

**This code is tested and works.**